# How to Instagram url for user in .net core 2.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, url-routing

How can I use the Instagram url in my project, for example.
https://www.instagram.com/tom

Comment: Answer: as you like.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. To access a specific user's feed through the Instagram API you must
   first register a new Instagram OAuth Client at
   http://instagram.com/developer/clients/register which your website
   will use to access the API.
2. Next you need to grant permission to the new application to access
   the Instagram API on your behalf, the easiest way to do this is by
   going to the Instagram authorization URL below, just replace the
   querystring parameters CLIENT-ID and REDIRECT-URI with the values
   from your client application:
3. You'll be prompted to give access to the application, then you'll be
   redirected back to the REDIRECT-URI with an access token appended to
   the end in the url fragment,
4. There are a couple of NuGet packages you can use to access the
   Instagram API, I went with the Skybrud.Social package because it
   looked easy to use, and it was, I was able to get the 9 latest
   images from a user feed with the following C# code in my MVC4
   controller:

**Full detail with example you can find here**: https://www.pointblankdevelopment.com.au/blog/126/display-instagram-user-feed-on-your-website-with-c-and-aspnet-mvc4

Comment: I dont think that was the question. I believe the question is how to use routing in .net core so you can have URLs like site.com/somebody